# (Explicit Binding) Customizing The Resolution Logic & Customizing The "Not Found" Behavior

Tags: php, laravel, data-binding, exception, routes

To explicitly bind a parameter to a  model and throwing a custom exception I have to (among other things) add the following to the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
$router->model('parameter', 'App\Model', function () {
    throw new CustomNotFoundException;
});
```

To customize the resolution logic of the explicit binding I have to add the following to the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
$router->bind('parameter', function ($parameter) {
    return App\Model::where('field', $parameter)->first();
});
```

My problem is that I need both but apparently can't. If I bind the parameter to the model and also customize the resolution logic it won't throw my `CustomNotFoundException`, instead it will throw the default `ModelNotFoundException`.

To clearly summarize my objective: I want to customize the resolution logic and throw a custom exception if it fails to find a record.

**EDIT** I have tried this as per a suggestion from @Maraboc:

```
$router->bind('parameter', function ($parameter) {
    try {
        return App\Model::where('field' => $parameter)->first();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new CustomNotFoundException;
    }
});
```

This will still throw a `ModelNotFoundException` for a reason I'm not aware.

Comment: Try to surround `App\Model::where('field', $parameter)->first();` with try catch to catch `ModelNotFoundException` and throw your `CustomNotFoundException` instead

Comment: @Maraboc I tried it but it's not working, maybe I did something wrong. Please check the edit I just made to the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$router->bind('parameter', function ($parameter) {
    try {
         return App\Model::where('field' => $parameter)->firstOrFail();
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        throw new CustomNotFoundException;
    }
});
```

OR in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` add this to the `render` method :

```
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
    throw new CustomNotFoundException;
}
```

And `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException as ModelNotFoundException;`

OR an other workaround is to do like so :

```
$router->bind('parameter', function ($parameter) {

    $model = App\Model::where('field' => $parameter)->first();

    if ( ! $model) {
        throw new CustomNotFoundException;
    }

    return $model;
});
```

Comment: The same thing happens, `ModelNotFoundException `.

Comment: That's sort of what I'm doing with other custom exceptions so this method doesn't fit in my current logic. I have many other exceptions with custom behavior in that render function already.

Comment: Yep, that works, it's not pretty but I can live with it for now until I find something better. Thanks! :)